# How can I get a block? (like a model)

Tags: magento-1.9

This may be a beginner question.

In order to get a model I use:

> Mage::getModel(folder/file);

I tried the same with a block (something like getBlock) but it keeps giving me an error.

Is there any other way to access a block? Which is the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('newmodule/newblock')->getYourFunction();
```

OR

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('newmodule/newblock')->getYourFunction();
```